# Realm Results array's count alway equal 1

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, realm, nsarray

i'm working on a QRCode scanner app, the logic is when device scanned the code, it will save the information of that code into Realm and user can see them in TableView.

But now im facing a problem, the Results array always return one element, even if i scanned many times.

Below is my code for saving qrcode object:

```
self.barcodesHandler = { barcodes in
        if !self.dispatched {
            self.dispatched = true
            for barcode in barcodes {
                print("Barcode found: type=" + barcode.type + " value=" + barcode.stringValue)
                let barcodeStringArray  = barcode.stringValue.components(separatedBy: ": ")
                let infoVC = ANSProductDetailViewController()
                self.product = ANSProductModel(name: barcodeStringArray[1], manufacturer: barcodeStringArray[2], registerLocation: barcodeStringArray[0], detailUrl: barcodeStringArray[3])
                infoVC.product = self.product
                DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {
                    infoVC.hidesBottomBarWhenPushed = true
                    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(infoVC, animated: true)
                })
                break
            }
            self.product.saveToLocal()
        }
    }
//ANSProductModel save method, self = ANSProductModel
func saveToLocal() {
    Realm.execute { (realm) in
        realm.add(self, update: true)
        print("Product saved")
    }
}
```

and code for retrieving them in TableView:

```
var productList: Results<ANSProductModel>!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    let realm = try! Realm()
    productList = realm.objects(ANSProductModel.self)
    tableView.register(UINib(nibName: "ANSProductHistoryCell", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "ANSProductHistoryCell")
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}
```

Please anyone can help me, i've tried a lot but still stuck with them. Thanks so much !

Comment: `Realm.execute()` isn't part of the Realm API. Can you post _all_ relevant code, the definitions of the model objects you are using, and any extensions on Realm you've written or otherwise are using?

Comment: Realm.excute() is just an wrapping method, i've tried by using sortedbyKeyPath method and it worked. However, this issues appeared again when i'm trying to save another model.

Comment: Again, please provide _all_ relevant code. We don't even know how your models are defined yet. If you don't provide your code we can't troubleshoot it.

Answer (score 0):

Based on `Real Swift 2.10.2` latest documentation (https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/), saving has been the same, so can you try this way?

```
func saveToLocal() {
    // Get the default Realm
    let realm = try! Realm()

    // Persist your data easily
    try! realm.write {
        realm.add(self)
        print("Product saved")
    }
}
```

Edit: Maybe you're saving the new data correctly, make sure you're reloading your `UITableView` after saving.